# HttpPost from Java does not work

Tags: java, json, http, post, request

I am trying to post a reply from Java to Booking extranet. I login correctly with a POST request but when i tried to send another POST to reply to an specific comment inside it doesn't work.

I've tried these options:

```
    private static void sendPostReply(String ses) throws IOException {

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(POST_URL_REPLY);
        httpPost.addHeader("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

        List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();      
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("review_id", "xxxxxxx"));
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("hotelier_response", "Some text..."));
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("review_language", "es"));
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("hotel_id", "xxxxx"));
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ses", ses));


        HttpEntity postParams = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters);
        httpPost.setEntity(postParams);
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setRedirectStrategy(new LaxRedirectStrategy()).build();
        CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        System.out.println("POST Response Status:: "
                + httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                httpResponse.getEntity().getContent()));

        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        reader.close();
        System.out.println(response);
        httpClient.close();


    }
```

This one is with json:

```
private static void sendPostReply(String ses) throws IOException {

    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(POST_URL_REPLY);

    JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    obj.put("review_id", "xxxxxxx");
    obj.put("hotelier_response", "Some text...");
    obj.put("review_language", "es");
    obj.put("hotel_id", "xxxxx");
    obj.put("ses", ses);
    array.add(obj);

    StringEntity urlParameters = new StringEntity(array.toString(), ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    System.out.println("Parameters in JSON: " + array.toString());

    httpPost.setEntity(urlParameters);
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setRedirectStrategy(new LaxRedirectStrategy()).build();
    CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

    System.out.println("POST Response Status:: "
            + httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            httpResponse.getEntity().getContent()));

    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    reader.close();
    System.out.println(response);
    httpClient.close();


}
```

No one of the above options works. I get the *ses* parameter from the login resquest and the *POST_URL_REPLY* is https://admin.booking.com/hotel/hoteladmin/json/save_hotelier_response.html I get back as response the html of the login page.

When i do that on the browser this is the request and the response:

```
Remote Address:5.57.17.51:443
Request URL:https://admin.booking.com/hotel/hoteladmin/json/save_hotelier_response.html
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Response Headers
view source
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Thu, 29 Oct 2015 15:07:59 GMT
Server:nginx
Set-Cookie:esadm=02UmFuZG9tSVYkc2RlIyh9YS6XGV7%2ByXx9B9vrkkmq65tc69pqRcxf4MXcYFF70RN83kZ4HoJED%2FY%3D; domain=booking.com; path=/; expires=Tue, 27-Oct-2020 15:07:58 GMT; secure; HttpOnly
Strict-Transport-Security:max-age=17280000
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By:en104admapp-03
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
Request Headers
view source
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:es-ES,es;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:348
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie:zz_cook_tms_seg1=2; cookie_notice_shown=1; bkng_bfp=8c9d744a312989cabdbe1ea29ae1871b; ut=e; cwd-extranet=1; slan=en; __utma=1.2120577969.1438246561.1441623510.1441874645.14; __utmz=1.1441623510.13.9.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided); zz_cook_tms_seg3=5; viewedBCheckBounce=true; ecid=2IqOfbo65RGKGF3Dt8%2BQbA%2B6; __CT_Data=gpv=13&apv_382_www06=13; WRUID=0; b=%7B%22rF%22%3A%22236371895%22%7D; utag_main=v_id:014ede2ce79f000a51192387713e0606d004c06500bd0$_sn:23$_ss:1$_st:1445953128206$_pn:1%3Bexp-session$ses_id:1445951328206%3Bexp-session; bkng=11UmFuZG9tSVYkc2RlIyh9YSvtNSM2ADX0Caiw3JuH2Uo0pWsRkQnSvvtDTBR3XkdG3wfBz0e9UYwouxaoMB3pBeIxqxW4965U%2FlH8VOJg6C%2F7TC82aQuLshkxwnDownIoLYAW8pNt0m7qPo6LxV8VdxmN9xPhU%2BVVoNcokaGWUV1BMSBKfaBKGFPxL%2FWW4j3fngigWHYGOn03Ek2e8tUlPA%3D%3D; auth_token=7726476937; esadm=02UmFuZG9tSVYkc2RlIyh9YS6XGV7%2ByXx9M2MskSM2cBY2culHWUCo4gfM7hOpRzp8eT4xzpWpigQ%3D; _ga=GA1.2.2120577969.1438246561
Host:admin.booking.com
Origin:https://admin.booking.com
Referer:https://admin.booking.com/hotel/hoteladmin/general/reviews.html?lang=en&ses=be8e85e657c9849afdc6beba32090217&hotel_id=xxxxx
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36
X-Booking-CSRF:320yVgAAAAA=fw7De7XXQczccmWIprcWXDvh6g3F0Rr_aNGtKI4ZseFJpxr0XXWo9i0lPSjeMWbX4j4yV6g3GtGaBbC9RuqsdQhjV_Q1nnog9noREdwibQIlY3MStA6SzTvkpQCJ8AxirEIUzpf1HUu19fS2tbidSZkS6iabuBMc0WvRGQ
X-FirePHP-Version:0.0.6
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Form Data
view source
view URL encoded
review_id:xxxxxxx
hotelier_response:Some text...
review_language:es
hotel_id:xxxxxxx
ses:be8e85e657c9849afdc6beba32090217
```

And the response:

```
   {"success":1,
"reply_html":"        
<div class=\"hreply\">\n            
<div class=\"hreply-heading\">\n                
<i class=\"icon-calendar\"></i><p><small class=\"text-primary\"> 2015-10-29 16:07:59</small></p>\n                
<div class=\"approved\">\n                    <p><small class=\"text-muted\">Waiting for approval </small></p><i class=\"icon-time\"></i>\n                
</div>\n            
</div>\n            
<div class=\"hreply-body\">\n            
<!-- Some text... -->\n                <p>Some text...</p>\n            
</div>\n        
</div>\n\n\n\n\n"
}
```

What am i doing wrong???

Regards!

Comment: I don't see anything technologically wrong. You send a request, you get a 200 success response. Working as designed. You don't get the response content you want, but that's between you and the owners of the site.

Comment: Yes i get the 200 OK status but the reply is not posted on Booking... so it's not working. The question is... why?? Because i am sending the data as it works in the webpage.

Comment: I can imagine the site has anti-spam features that may be blocking your attempts to circumvent using the site as designed - in a browser. Again: you'll have to discuss that with the site owners. I'm sure they'll love to hear you're trying to do this. And perhaps they actually have a better solution that you can use rather than doing manual HTTP post hacks, such as a proper webservice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i solved it.

I just have to get the cookies from my login POST request and then put them into my reply POST resquest and it works!

Answer (score 0):

```
     DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        DefaultRedirectStrategy redirect = new Redirect() {
            public boolean isRedirected(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, HttpContext context) {
                boolean isRedirect = false;
                try {
                    isRedirect = super.isRedirected(request, response, context);
                } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (!isRedirect) {
                    int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                    if (responseCode == 301 || responseCode == 302) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return isRedirect;
            }
        };
        httpclient.setRedirectStrategy(redirect);
```

///////////////////

```
public class Redirect extends DefaultRedirectStrategy {

    @Override
    public HttpUriRequest getRedirect(HttpRequest request,
                                      HttpResponse response, HttpContext context)
            throws ProtocolException {
        URI uri = getLocationURI(request, response, context);
        String method = request.getRequestLine().getMethod();
        if (method.equalsIgnoreCase(HttpHead.METHOD_NAME)) {
            return new HttpHead(uri);
        } else {
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(uri);
            StringEntity entity = null;
            try {
                entity = new StringEntity("{\"name\":\"" + _name + "\", \"ttl\":10000000000000}");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            entity.setContentType("application/json");
            httppost.setEntity(entity);
            return httppost;
        }
    }
}
```